# Finding a mistake in eigenvectors calculation

Tags: linear-algebra

Following an example from my textbook, we are looking for eigenvectors of a particular matrix with complex eigenvalues. The original matrix looks like 
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
  -1 & 2  \\
  -1 & -3  \\
  \end{matrix}\right)$$
with eigenvalues $$-2 \pm 2i$$
Inserting -$2+i$ into our $A- \lambda I$ version of the matrix, we get 
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
  1-i & 2  \\
  -1 & -1-i  \\
  \end{matrix}\right)$$
So far, I'm with them all the way. At this point, the eigenvector corresponding to this matrix is given to be 
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
   2  \\
  -1+i  \\
  \end{matrix}\right)$$
This is where they lose me. I calculate the eigenvector by solving the second row $[(-1)x_1 - (-1-i)x_2 = 0]$ for $x_2$ in terms of $x_1$ which gives us: $$x_2 = \frac{x_1}{-1-i}\tag{*}$$ and the eigenvector $$\left(\matrix{x_1\\x_2}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
   \frac{1}{-1-i}  \\
  1  \\
  \end{matrix}\right)\tag{**}$$
which is not a scalar multiple of their eigenvector. Multiplying this vector with $-1-i$ we get
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
  1  \\
  -1-i  \\
  \end{matrix}\right)$$
& multiplying their eigenvector with ${\frac{\overline{-1+i}}{2}}$ we get
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
  -1-i  \\
  1  \\
  \end{matrix}\right)$$

ie the "inverse" of what I get. This seems to be the general case, every time I calculate eigenvectors I get the mirror image of the result the book has. Since these vectors in general seem to be linearly independent (mine and theirs), they answers aren't equivalent. Am I missing something regarding these complex eigenvectors?

Comment: Calculation from $(*)$ to $(**)$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $x_2=\frac{x_1}{-1-i}$ gives you the vector $(1, \frac{1}{-1-i}$, not the vector $(\frac{1}{-1-i}, 1)$. You set $x_1$ to $1$ and then $x_2$ becomes the fraction.

Comment: Of course, thank you very much! Looking back on my notes, I made the exact same mistake of mixing up the parameters on two different problems, which is why I was "consistently" wrong. Again, thanks for your time!